# Getting the for loop to ignore the blank/null value

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How can the code below be modified such that I would be able to get my for loop to ignore the blank/null value that is a selectable option available to the user in the color select box?

Here is the code in question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      var x = document.getElementById("colors")
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        alert(x.options[i].value)
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="colors">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a availability check:

```
if(value) alert(value)
```

#### Sample

```js
function test() {
  var x = document.getElementById("colors")
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x.options[i].value) alert(x.options[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="colors">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="">Test</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()">
```

Comment: I would be able to get my for loop to ignore the blank/null value .In your code for iterating over null /blank value

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Yes, I misunderstood your comment, assuming you meant that the condition will pass with whitespace-only strings. Sounded like you were saying the alert would not show for whitespace strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `i=1` in your for loop instead of `i=0`.

Comment: This is not the solution. OP can have blank value somewhere in middle as well